# Linux Directory Access Problem: Permission Denied """In Root"""

Tags: linux

When login through root on HP-tru Unix server, I am trying to access a directory, it is saying "Permission Denied".. Also, an sh file is also not able to execute through same root access..

I have checked the permission of the directory as well as for sh file through ls-ltr.. It is also fine.. `Root System rwx-rwx-rwx--`

What could be the possible cause, and how to correct it..

Thanks.

Comment: That's an unusual permission string; the dashes should be missing.  Also, NEVER have public write permission on the root directory.

Comment: As Jonathan has pointed out, would you mind providing accurate information?

Comment: This belongs on serverfault.

Answer (score 1):

Is the directory mounted from some other system, such as an NFS share? That would limit access to files. You may also want to check the mount options (i.e. cat /etc/mtab) to make sure that none of the options prevent writing and executing.